# IntegerSet in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am having problems with an assignment. The assignment is to create an IntegerSet
an IntegerSet is an array of 100 elements that represents the numbers from 0 to 99
for example if the number 5 is present in set a then `a[5] = 1`, an empty set is an array of zeroes.

I created a class called IntegerSet and here is the code in integerSet.cpp

```
#include "integerset.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

IntegerSet::IntegerSet(){
    int temp[100] = {0};
    set = temp;
}

IntegerSet::IntegerSet(int * setPtr) {
    set = setPtr;
}

void IntegerSet::insertElement(int toInsert) {
    if(toInsert < 100 && toInsert >= 0) {
        set[toInsert] = 1;
    }
}

void IntegerSet::deleteElement(int toDelete) {
    if (toDelete < 100 && toDelete >= 0 ) {
        set[toDelete] = 0;
    }
}

IntegerSet * IntegerSet::unionOfSets(IntegerSet * otherPtr) {
    int newSet[100] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        if (this->set[i] == 1 || otherPtr->set[i] == 1) {
            newSet[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    return new IntegerSet(newSet);
}

IntegerSet * IntegerSet::intersectionOfSets(IntegerSet* otherPtr) {
    int newSet[100] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if(this->set[i] == 1 && otherPtr->set[i] == 1){
            newSet[i] = 1; 
        }
    }
    return new IntegerSet(newSet);
}

bool IntegerSet::isEmpty(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if(set[i] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}  

bool IntegerSet::isEqualTo(IntegerSet * otherPtr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if(this->set[i] != otherPtr->set[i]) {
            return false;                
        }        
    }
    return true;
}

void IntegerSet::printSet() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        cout << "---" << endl;
    } else { 
        for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
            if(set[i] == 1) {
                cout << i << ' ';
            }
        }
        cout << endl;        
    }
}   

IntegerSet::~IntegerSet() { 
    delete[] set;
}
```

The class has private member `int * set;`.

This is the main function used to test my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<new>
#include "integerset.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IntegerSet * set1Ptr = new IntegerSet();
    set1Ptr->insertElement(1);
    set1Ptr->insertElement(2);
    set1Ptr->insertElement(3);
    set1Ptr->insertElement(50);
    IntegerSet * set2Ptr = new IntegerSet();
    set2Ptr->insertElement(0);
    set2Ptr->insertElement(3);
    set2Ptr->insertElement(2);
    set2Ptr->insertElement(51);
    set2Ptr->insertElement(100);
    set2Ptr->insertElement(99);
    IntegerSet * set3Ptr = set1Ptr->unionOfSets(set2Ptr);
    IntegerSet * set4Ptr = set1Ptr->intersectionOfSets(set2Ptr);
    cout << "First Set" << endl;
    set1Ptr->printSet();
    cout << "Second Set" << endl;
    set2Ptr->printSet();
    cout << "Equal ? : " << set1Ptr->isEqualTo(set2Ptr) << endl;
    cout << "Intersection : " << endl;
    set4Ptr->printSet();
    cout << "Union : " << endl;
    set3Ptr->printSet();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This the output I get when running

```
First Set
16 19 35 45 46 54 66 84
Second Set
0 1 10 12 13 14 19 35 45 46 54 66 84
Equal ? : 1
Intersection :
16 19 35 45 46 54 66 84 98
Union :
0 1 10 12 13 14 19 35 45 46 54 66 84 98
```

I tried tracing and I have no idea what's wrong, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are the pointers part of the assignment? main doesn't need any and the functions don't need to return any. Also, it seems like you're assigning a pointer to point to an array you create in your constructor. When your constructor ends, it will be a dangling pointer.

Comment: thanks for the quick response works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IntegerSet::IntegerSet(){
   int temp[100] = {0};
   set = temp;
}
```

That is creating a local array of 100 elements and storing a pointer to it in the member `set`. The problem here is that the lifetime of `temp` is restricted to the constructor, and as soon as the constructor exits, the array is destroyed and what you have is a dangling pointer (a pointer to a block of memory that is not valid).

If you need to use pointers then you should dynamically allocate the memory and make sure to release it in the destructor. If not, you can declare the array as a member attribute of your type and avoid the pointers altogether.

Comment: And of course a destructor calls for the rule of 3 (or more) :)

Comment: thanks :>  i thought since something pointed to it it won't be destroyed.

Comment: If you want something to not be destroyed, declare it as `static`.

Comment: @Chris: That is not really a good advice for someone that might not know all the implications. In particular, if the array was `static` in the constructor then it would be shared by all instances of `IntegerSet` and the program would fail for other reasons (there would be a single set in the whole program.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, that is a good argument; better to just stick with things that work fully than to introduce something that only works partially.

Answer (score 1):

remember, for every "new" you are calling, you have to have a delete.

```
IntegerSet::IntegerSet(){


           int temp[100] = {0};
           set = temp;



}
```

I don't think that your constructor makes sense to what you are trying to accomplish.
In your destructor you include:

```
 IntegerSet::~IntegerSet() { 
 delete[] set;
 }
```

the delete is great IF you have dynamically allocated the array in the first place. If you want to keep up with all of this unnessesary pointer stuff, your constructor should look like this

```
IntegerSet::IntegerSet(){

           set = new int[100];
         for(int i; i < 100; i++)
              set[i] = 0;


}
```

I would not use pointers or dynamically allocated memory at all in this case. The arrays are of no need to grow or shrink. They also do not need to exist after the main function exists. Try to simplify it without all the pointers.